# How to install Marlin File Manager in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-16.04

[image]

The above screenshot is downloaded for reference only.

I found the following commands to install in order to get the file manager structure as shown in the screenshot.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marlin-devs/marlin-daily
sudo apt update
sudo apt install marlin
```

But when I try them the repository is not added, and I get the following error:

[image: error message]

How can I install Marlin File Manager in Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but as you can see, the developers haven't added support for this file Manager for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I wrote the review of file managers http://linuxsoid.com/top-4-best-file-manager-for-linux wanted to install the Marlin, but even after checking their repository http://ppa.launchpad.net/marlin-devs/marlin-daily/ubuntu/dists/ 'll see that support Xenial yet, worth the wait, maybe the developers will add support.

Also worth a read response on the page https://answers.launchpad.net/marlin/+question/252528 it seems the project is abandoned.